# Console app reposition blinking cursor

Tags: vb.net, console, cursor

I am pretty new to building console applications and i have been following some tutorials and it's been pretty helpful in my learning development.
I have been trying to make my own console application and I wanted to add some cool stuff to it, for example.

Below is an example of my menu. I would like to reposition  the blinking cursor in-line and at the end of the phrase where it says, `"Please select item:"`.

I would also like for each of my menu items to appear in a different colour without affecting the * border

I was trying to run `dir *.pst /s /w /p` or `chkdsk /f` using `process.start()` but all it does is start the command prompt shell or do nothing at all.

```
'sub main()`
'Console.writeline("************************")`
'Console.writeline("* [1] item 1           *")`
`Console.writeline("* [2] item 2           *")`
`Console.writeline("* [3] item 3           *")`
`Console.writeline("* Pleas select item:   *")`
`Console.writeline("************************")`
`Dim opts As String console.readline()`
`seclect case opts`
`case is = "1"`
`call item1()`
`case is = "2"`
`call item()`
`case is ="3"`
`call item3()`
`case else ="0"`
`console.writeline("This will end the program")`
`console.writeline("Press any key to continue")`
`console.readkey()`
`end` 
`end select`
`end Sub`
`sub item1()`
`console.writeline("this is item 1")`
`console.readkey()`
`process.start main()`
`end sub`
`sub item2()`
`console.writeline("this is item 2")`
`console.readkey()`
`process.start main()`
`end sub`
`sub item3()`
`console.writeline("this is item 3")`
`console.readkey()`
`process.start main()`
`end sub`
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be easiest by clearing the console first with [Console.Clear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.clear(v=vs.110).aspx).  This will make sure everything is out of the way and allows you draw wherever you want.  You can set the cursor position with [Console.SetCursorPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx) and the color with [Console.ForegroundColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor(v=vs.110).aspx) before you draw the menu with the standard Console.Write()/Console.WriteLine() commands.